# How to reference plugins and Js files

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, copyright-display

I finished my website recently  but I don't know how to reference the different JS plugins that I use, and bootstrap too.

Best regards

Comment: What do you mean by reference? Do you mean include them in your website?

Comment: I mean the copiright ... must include on the website?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about copyright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boostrap is released under the MIT license.  [Here is their license](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE).

> ...subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

I don't think you need to reference it visibly, but you can't strip the copyright information out of the code.

In general, check the websites of the software you are including, particularly their licensing information when you want to know what you can and can't do with it or how to cite them.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the copyright and licensing info is included in the js files, as long as you don't delete this info there's no need to do anything else.

Comment: I mean the copyright ... must include it on the website?

Comment: ah ok I'll edit my answer